# Git clone failing on Windows-Flutter,iOS

Tags: ios, windows, git, macos, flutter

I'm trying to clone the git repository that was created initially using mac. I'm getting the below error while cloning on Windows machine.

*error: invalid path build\ios/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/dgph*

P.S: I'm able to clone it on my mac machine with no problem.

Comment: Mac uses `/` in file paths and windows uses `\\`

Comment: The *real* question now is: Why is your build output directory in your repository?

Answer (score -1):

Tell the owner of the repo to delete a folder named build/ios. Thats what i did to solve it on my hand.

Comment: How does it answers the question?